# Set click event on matching elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I state that I am not an expert in Javascript / jQuery and the question may be trivial.
I want to set the click event to each element  page.
I wrote this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').each(function (index, element) {
        $(this).click(e, getPluginDetail);
    });
});

function getPluginDetail(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // load details...
}
```

However when I start the page I get an error: e is not defined.
Can you help me?

Thank you!

Comment: because you havent defined an `e` variable, the first argument to click is either an EventData object, or a function reference

Comment: Thanks Patrick, how can I change the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, no need to iterate over each anchor element. Just do

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(getPluginDetail);
});

function getPluginDetail(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // load details...
}
```

The reason `e` was `undefined` is because you did not pass it in the click function declaration callback and it was not defined elsewhere.

**Update**

When you include the function reference like above, the `event` object will get passed automatically. This is because the browser automatically assigns the `event` object as the first parameter to the click handler function.

See http://javascript.info/tutorial/obtaining-event-object

Comment: you do not need to make a wrapper function, just pass getPluginDetail, the event object gets passed automatically

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to iterate i.e. `each` to bind event and Just pass the function reference to when binding event.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a').click(getPluginDetail);
});
```